# How can I add plugin to Nagios Core 4.X

Tags: unix, nagios

I would like to ask, how can I add plugin (below) to the nagios core 4.X

```
http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/ICMP/chech_hping/details
```

I always got an error:

```
Error: Service check command 'check_hping' specified in service 'HPING3' for host 'cam_chodba' not defined anywhere
```

I have defined command in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/commands.cfg` :

```
define command{
    command_name    check-ping-on-port
    command_line    /usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_hping $HOSTADDRESS$ 100 500 $ARG1$
    }
```

and host and service in `/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/switch.cfg` :

```
define host{
    use             generic-switch
    host_name       cam_chodba
    alias           cam_chodba
    address         1.2.3.4
    check_command   check-ping-on-port
    hostgroups      switches
    }

define service{
        use                     generic-service
        host_name               cam_chodba
        service_description     HPING3
        check_command           check_hping
        }
```

when I'm trying run just a command, its running -->

```
root@onedata-desktop:~# /home/onedata/Downloads/check_hping 188.123.99.171 200 500 10201
OK: Average response time 10 ms; packet loss 0%
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You defined the command as `command_name check-ping-on-port` but are calling it by the exe name in the service `check_command check_hping`. Change the first one to `check_command check-ping-on-port` and you should be good.

```
define service{
    use                     generic-service
    host_name               cam_chodba
    service_description     HPING3
    check_command           check-ping-on-port
    }
```

Comment: thank you, now I can see the service in the web interface, but the result is probably wrong, nagios shows me that service is down, but service is definitely UP, I think the problem is in arguments...
`define service{

        use                     generic-service

        host_name               cam_chodba

        service_description     Kamery

        check_command           check-ping-on-port!188.123.99.171!10201
        }`

Comment: this should be usage:
`$0 [host] [warning max rtt] [critical max rtt] [port]`

Comment: Different question now. :) Post a new question separately.